# Making json to hash, then comparing this hash with another hash in perl

Tags: json, perl, hash

I am having 2 files (json file and pid file). The format for json file is:

```
{
 "connection": {
  "file": {
   "file_connection_1": {
    "CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION": "",
    "CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL": "",
    "CONN_NAME": "file_connection_1",
    "FILE_DIR": "/home/directory"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Format for pid:

```
<General>
 "CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION": "YES"
 "CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL": "PRTCL"
 "CONN_NAME": "file_connection_1"
 "FILE_DIR": "/home/directory"
</General>
```

I want to convert both the files into hashes and then compare the values of the keys (eg. CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION or CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL...). Get the values from pid and insert them into json file hash, if not present.
I am able to convert the files to hash, but not clear about how to compare the keys and copy the value from pid hash to json hash.

Comment: where and which.......... This two points are missed in your question. Where --> server side or front end and Which language you are using.

Comment: @Hema According to the tags and the question title, the OP is using Perl.

Comment: You should add the code you already have. How do you convert the files into hashes? What do the resulting data structures look like? Show them. You can [edit] your question to add these details.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand the question, you have two hashes that have the same keys. If the first one does not have a value for a certain key, you want to put the value from the other hash there.

Because you did not provide how you create those hashes, I came up with my own solution for that. You can probably disregard it. I used [Config::General](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General) and some trickery to get rid of `"` and `:` to read the pid file, and [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) for the JSON.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::General;
use JSON 'decode_json';
use Data::Dumper;

# read the pid file
my %cfg_pid = Config::General->new(
    -NormalizeOption => sub { my $x = shift; $x =~ s/^"|":$//g; $x; }, 
    -NormalizeValue  => sub { my $x = shift; $x =~ s/^"|"$//g; $x },
    -ConfigFile      => \*DATA
)->getall;

# read the json file
my $json = <<'JSON';
{
 "connection": {
  "file": {
   "file_connection_1": {
    "CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION": "",
    "CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL": "",
    "CONN_NAME": "file_connection_1",
    "FILE_DIR": "/home/directory"
   }
  }
 }
}
JSON

my $cfg_json = decode_json($json);

# this is before
print Dumper $cfg_json;

# actual part that you want
foreach my $key ( keys %{ $cfg_pid{General} } ) {
    $cfg_json->{connection}->{file}->{file_connection_1}->{$key} = $cfg_pid{General}->{$key}
        unless $cfg_json->{connection}->{file}->{file_connection_1}->{$key};
}

# and this is after
print Dumper $cfg_json;

__DATA__
<General>
 "CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION": "YES"
 "CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL": "PRTCL"
 "CONN_NAME": "file_connection_1"
 "FILE_DIR": "/home/directory"
</General>
```

All it really does is iterate the keys of the pid file hash, and check in the json hash if there is a value of that key. If that value is not true (that means the key doesn't exist, the value is `undef`, an empty string `q{}` or `0`), it will set it to the value of the pid file hash. You could of course also check for empty string explicitly.

The output is as follows.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'connection' => {
        'file' => {
            'file_connection_1' => {
                'FILE_DIR'             => '/home/directory',
                'CONN_NAME'            => 'file_connection_1',
                'CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL'  => '',
                'CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION' => ''
            }
        }
    }
};
$VAR1 = {
    'connection' => {
        'file' => {
            'file_connection_1' => {
                'FILE_DIR'             => '/home/directory',
                'CONN_NAME'            => 'file_connection_1',
                'CLOUD_CONN_PROTOCOL'  => 'PRTCL',
                'CLOUD_AUTHENTICATION' => 'YES'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. I converted the files to hash in the same way you did. Sorry, I did not provide you with the code. Your answer seems to be giving the correct result, but I dont want to hard code those values. I have just given you a part of json. The json, that I am using, contains 5-10 categories like 'connection' and then different sub categories. I cannot hard code all the categories. Also, I was thinking to compare the key from pid to json and when it matches, then get the value. I don't know how to compare key of different structured hashes.

Comment: Also, can we check in this code: `$cfg_json->{connection}->{file}->{file_connection_1}->{$key}` if value(hash reference name) before $key is equal to 'file_connection_1' or second last value(hash reference name) equal to 'file'?

Comment: @JustStarted please update your question and include a second category in both of the files. You didn't mention that the categories are dynamic. I don't understand what you mean with your second comment. Try saying it in a different way.